# Swift share on facebook

Tags: xcode, swift, facebook, share, facebook-share

I am having trouble sharing a link on facebook from my iOS app.
I was using the below code and it was working a few months ago.
The only setup I used to do was "*import Social*"

```
@IBAction func facebookShareButtonTouched(sender: AnyObject) {
    if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeFacebook) {
        let fbShare:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)

        fbShare.addURL(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "https://www.xxx.ro/info/article/\(newsObject.id!)"))
        self.presentViewController(fbShare, animated: true, completion: nil)


    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Facebook account to share.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)


        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Now it opens the facebook share dialog, but it does not contain any link.
Anybody knows what it changed?

Comment: Can you screenshot it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

```
fbShare.addURL(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "https://www.xxx.ro/info/article/\(newsObject.id!)"))
```

with this

```
fbShare.addURL(NSURL("https://www.xxx.ro/info/article/\(newsObject.id!)"))
```

Answered considering you want share URL - `"https://www.xxx.ro/info/article/xid"`